# Difference between spring.session.timeout property and <session-timeout> tag in web.xml

Tags: spring-boot, redis, web.xml, httpsession

Trying to store my HttpSession using Redis in Spring Boot. All guides mention session timeout properties - like spring.session.timeout - and previously I used to define timeout in web.xml. Can't figure\find out the difference between those two.

When I comment out timeout in `web.xml` and use property - for example 1 minute timeout - it is not being 1 minute after deploy. Are those two ways connected somehow? Or those are completely different things?

**UPD 1**: Also I am using `@EnableRedisHttpSession` with no args, if that affects it

Comment: How do you deploy the app? As JAR or WAR?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I am deploying it as WAR on tomcat

Comment: I think you must set server.servlet.session.timeout

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I changed the property and cleaned/re-deployed war -> my property set 1m session did not expired after that time, so it did not helped. Thank you anyway)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.